# Visual Studio how to change path to settings file

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My "Documents" folder path is not accessible and I need to change the path to the `CurrentSettings.vssettings` file. The problem is that Import wizard does not work.

[image]

After I click on the Next button, the wizard disappear.

So the question is, is it possible to change the path manually in some config file somewhere or what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and save the currentSettings.vssettings file by going in Visual Studio under the tab Tools -> Options, under the Environment section, in Import and Export Settings. As in the example: [Tools/Options/Environment/Import and Export Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duoIC.png)